# Function that maps (binary representation of) $x \in [0,1]$ to number given by the “even bits” of $x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, lebesgue-measure, binary, cantor-set

I’m just wondering if there’s a name for the function defined below.

> Write $x$ uniquely in base 2 (i.e. not ending in an infinite string of ones) as $x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_k}{2^k}$. Define $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x_{2k}}{2^k}$.

I’m not having luck with Google. The closest thing I get is the “dyadic transformation” function, which might be similar? Maybe it has something to do with Cantor functions? (Also apologies to mods as I have no idea how to tag this. The chosen tags are based on topics covered in a course where this example came from, so I’m hoping it looks familiar to someone in that area.)

Ultimately, I’m interested in what I can say about the integrability of this function, but first just trying to understand it.

Comment: So this function is continuous. Let $b_k(x)$ denote $k$-th bit of $x$. Now assume that sequence $x_{n}\to x$ as $n\to \infty$, then for all $k$, we have $b_k(x_{n})=b_{k}(x)$ for all $n>n_0(k)$ (in other words $k$-th bits of $x_{n}$ converge to $k$-th bits of $x$). In particular even bits of $x_{2n}$ converge to even bits of $x$. This implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. Since every continuous function is integrable, $f(x)$ is integrable.

Comment: That would be the x component of the interval-to-square bijection.

Comment: @C614 I doubt that $f$ is continuous. For $x=0.1_2$, $f(0.1_2) = 0_2$; while for any $0.01_2\le x < 0.1_2$ with $x_2 = 1$, $f(x) = f(0.01\ldots_2) = 0.1\ldots_2 \ge 0.1_2$.

Comment: @peterwhy thanks for pointing that out,  I made a mistake. Maybe the argument can still be salvaged for the values of $x$ that are not of the form $a/2^b$, where $a,b$ are integers. In other words if $x$ does not end in infinite sequence of zeroes, then $f$ is continuous at $x$, would that be right?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Wouldn't that be the function $f(x) = \sum_{k=0} \frac{x_k}{2^{2k}}$ or something?

Comment: It would all right. Still, what I said before is also true.